# Tag for new-in-10 process control functionality

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Do we need a new tag for the new [process control functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DirectControlOfExternalProcesses.html) of version 10?

I went ahead and created [process-control](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process-control) but I'm looking for community approval before using it more times.

Also, it's not clear what is the best name for it.  Internally it seems to be called `ProcessLink` but this name doesn't appear in the documentation.

Comment: [tag:process-control] seems good to have

Comment: What would the tag wiki look like?

Comment: @m_goldberg I started a tag wiki.

Comment: @Szabolcs. Looks good.